# Convert each attribute of a node into its sibling node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file with data in this format

```
<export>
  <timestamp itst="1478582248">2016-11-08T05:17:28Z</timestamp>
</export>
```

I would like to convert each attribute of a node into its sibling node.

I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />   
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is creating a nested or a child node instead of a sibling node.

```
<timestamp>
  <itst>1478582248</itst>2016-11-08T05:17:28Z</timestamp>
```

Expected output

```
<timestamp>2016-11-08T05:17:28Z</timestamp>
<itst>1478582248</itst>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Comment: Adding the full XSL code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template would work **if** you also had another template similar to:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Apparently you have a different template handling the parent element - one that applies templates to its child attributes **within** the `xsl:copy` instruction. But you're not showing us that part of your code, so we are forced to guess.

Comment: Thanks, but this part is already there. I have added it in the question above. What am I missing?

Comment: @AmitSaxena, you don't have the template that Michael posted in your XSLT. And you have the identity transformation template in there which you clearly don't want for attributes as you want to transform them and not copy them with the identity transformation template and you don't want for element nodes as you don't want to copy the attributes but want to transform them to siblings.

Comment: @AmitSaxena, see Michael's template together with your original template working to produce a sibling from the attribute in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxWZS6S.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin and Michael! This works! I am new at XSL, will try to understand how it works :)